# How to invoke methods of a class (in java) when class name and method name are stored in two different strings

Tags: java, class, jsp

Well, not sure if the question sounds a little weird but let me try to put forth the clarification :

I have a JSP page. On this JSP page, I am calling a java class defined in one of my packages under my projects. This class connects to database and access a table which has got fields namely - functionname, function class. Now I am able to retrieve in my JSP the two strings, lets say -

```
String funName = "ComFunctions";
String className = "funLog");
```

Now, I want to invoke this function using this class name i.e. basically something like - className.funName

Is it possible in Java? Actually, these functions and class names will be retrieved in a for loop, so I can't directly call using real classname but have to use strings.

Kindly suggest if there is a way or worl around or if the question is still unclear.

I tried the following approach so far but no luck -

```
Class c = Class.forName(className);
Object o = c.newInstance();
Method m = c.getMethod(funName, String.class); // Not sure what is supposed to be second parameter here i.e. after funName
```

Error - the above code gives " No class found error". And i made sure that class is there under the package. Even adding package name i.e. packge.classname didnt help and it says "Symbol not found" for package name.

Any pointers please?

Example class that I am trying to invoke -

```
package mypackage;

public class ComFunctions extends WDriverInitialize{

    public static void main(String[] args){


    }



    public static void funLog(String username){


        System.out.println(userName);


    }



}
```

Comment: Ha ha, pointers, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the compiled class is in the webapp's classpath (ie, WEB-INF/classes) and use the FQN (ie, add the package name).  You could also make a JAR file of your classes and add that to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Also, the extra parameter in getMethod is to fetch a method with the matching parameters (ie, in your example, one that takes a String

Comment: You may find this lib handy as well - it makes it easier to call methods by reflection (as you are doing) http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html

Comment: Thanks Tom for such a prompt reply. So I am using `netbeans 7.1.1 and apache 7.0.3`. I could see .class files under `\myproject\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\mypackage`. Still not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I suspect it may be because you're not giving the parameter types (see the also part of my answer).  Give a full example of a class/method  in your question.

Comment: added example in my questions Tom.

Comment: Class.forName("mypackage.ComFunctions") still gives you a not found exception?  Does this code work if you write it in a static main? (ie, not in a webapp)

Comment: Yes Tom :(...very weird I know... both the classes in same package...syas `can not find symbol, variable mypackage`...

Comment: ok, check your package name.  in your main method do this;  System.out.println(ComFunctions.class.getName());

Comment: it returns `mypackage.ComFunctions`

Comment: well, so, then, in the main code, Class.forName("mypackage.ComFunctions") should work without a not found exception.  If this does not work in a JSP, sounds like you have a classpath problem.  Try the same code in a JSP scriplet (<%= ComFunctions.class.getName();  %>)

Comment: Tom, i tried `System.out.print(ComFunctions.class.getName());` and it works and gives me `mypackage.ComFunctions` when tried in another class. So how shall I invoke a method of ComFunctions using string...lets say str1 ="ComFunctions"

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one piece of the puzzle, and that's the method arguments. Without it, you can't really be sure what method `funName` is referring to, and what arguments to pass to it.

And of course, the class needs to be in the classpath.

Comment: NilsH - well I get your point but its throwing error before arguments even. Could you please assist with -  the class needs to be in the classpath. ?? I am able to compile classed with netbeans, what else am I supposed to do? thanks for the help !!

Comment: If it's a webapp, then put the class files in `WEB-INF/classes`, or if it's a separate project, put the resulting jar file in `WEB-INF/lib`. And you make sure you refer to the class by it's full name, that is, including the package name.

Comment: If it is a properly configured web project, then it should end up in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: oh yes NilsH, I could see - `myproject\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\mypackagepackage` and all compiles .class files under it..the one that I am trying to call in my JSP. Also, I tried using full name `mypackage.classname` but it says `symbol not found` for mypackage. I am using netbeans and everything else works perfect. Stucked here.

Comment: if you files are within `mypackagepackage`, then the full classname is `mypackagepackage.classname`.

Comment: its simply that I am unable to call classname.methodname(parameter) in any java class using strings for class and methods...lets leave jsp apart....so if you could point me?

Comment: Then show us the code of the class it can't find. And also the structure of your war.

Comment: the code of class is as added in question, how to put the structure of war here?

Comment: If that class is inside a folder called `mypackagepackage`, then your folder structure is wrong. Move it to a folder called `mypackage`.

Comment: I tried to call `package mypackage;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Class c = Class.forName(mypackage.ComFunctions);
    }}` but even i doesn't recognize mypackage :(. what the hack i ma doing wrong here.

Comment: that class is under a folder called `mypackage` only

Comment: It should be `Class.forName("mypackage.ComFunction")`. But the best way to check if you can use the class is just `import mypackage;` and then `new ComFunctions()`.

Comment: same stupid error even after `import mypackage.*;`...sorry for taking so much of your time buddy.

Comment: Then it cannot have been compiled correctly, or you project is not set up correctly.

Comment: well, i believe project should be set up okay as i only used few classes and that too using netbeans...anyways, if i could figure it out, would surely put it here...thanks for all the help friend.